# Extract regex matches, and not groups, in data frames rows in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am a novice in coding and I generally use R for this (stringr) but I started to learn also Python's syntax.

I have a data frame with one column generated from an imported excel file. The values in this column contain both capital and smallcase characters, symbols and numbers.

I would like to generate a second column in the data frame containing only some of these words included in the first column according to a regex pattern.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["THIS IS A TEST 123123. s.m.", "THIS IS A Test test 123 .s.c.e", "TESTING T'TEST 123 da."],columns=['Test'])

df
```

Now, to extract what I want (words in capital case), in R I would generally use:

```
df <- str_extract_all(df$Test, "\\b[A-Z]{1,}\\b", simplify = FALSE)
```

to extract the matches of the regular expression in different data frame rows, which are:

```
* THIS IS A TEST
* THIS IS A
* TESTING T TEST
```

I couldn't find a similar solution for Python, and the closest I've got to is the following:

```
df["Name"] = df["Test"].str.extract(r"(\b[A-Z]{1,}\b)", expand = True)
```

Unfortunately this does not work, as it exports only the *groups* rather than the *matches* of the regex. I've tried multiple strategies, but also `str.extractall` does not seem to work ("TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index)

How can I extract the information I want with Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you can try:

```
df["Name"] = df["Test"].str.extractall(r"(\b[A-Z]{1,}\b)")
                       .unstack().fillna('').apply(' '.join, 1)
```

[EDIT]:
Here is a shorter version I discovered by looking at the doc:

```
 df["Name"] = df["Test"].str.extractall(r"(\b[A-Z]{1,}\b)").unstack(fill_value='').apply(' '.join, 1)
```

Comment: This solution, did work, thank you.
I will try to figure out why this happened and what all the commands you used do, but it's a good start for me to understand how Python is different from R.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track of getting the pattern. This solution uses regular expression, join and map.

```
 df['Name'] = df['Test'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r"\b[A-Z\s]+\b", x)))
```

Result:

```
  Test  Name
0   THIS IS A TEST 123123. s.m.     THIS IS A TEST
1   THIS IS A Test test 123 .s.c.e  THIS IS A
2   TESTING T'TEST 123 da.          TESTING T TEST
```