# How can I search for a prefix in a panda column, then if found, return that prefix+the next 11 characters in a new column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains invoice numbers in a variety of formats from different payments. I need to search for the prefix 'SIN' in column INVOICE NUMBER, and then if found, return SIN+the next 11 characters to a new column. The original data is:

```
   Payer      Amount  INVOICE NUMBER                       
0  Client A   345.34                         SINDE19-000032
1  Client B   450.00  48372HNFFSINNL18-003421SINNL18-012374
2  Client C  2403.34                             SINGB09584
3  Client D  1492.33                       KSKH97444 SI3232
```

If there are multiple versions of SINxxx..., I would like to return the two invoice numbers in the new column, separated by a comma.

The final dataframe should look like:

```
   Payer      Amount  INVOICE NUMBER                        TIDY
0  Client A   345.34                         SINDE19-000032 SINDE19-000032
1  Client B   450.00  48372HNFFSINNL18-003421SINNL18-012374 SINNL18-003421,SINNL18-012374
2  Client C  2403.34                             SINGB09584 NaN
3  Client D  1492.33                       KSKH97444 SI3232 NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do this. Either you can use the `map` function with a regex:

```py
df['TIDY'] = df['INVOICE NUMBER'].map(lambda x: ','.join(re.findall(r'SIN.{11}', x)))
```

This uses the `map` function to first extract the regex matches and then join them with the `,` as a delimiter for the complete column. Alternatively, you can use the `Series.str.extractall` function to do the same, as shown in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797875/extract-regex-matches-and-not-groups-in-data-frames-rows-in-python):

```py
df['TIDY'] = df['INVOICE NUMBER'].str.extractall(r'(SIN.{11})').unstack(fill_value='').apply(','.join, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this output will give you two columns for the first SIN and the second, It's what you want?

```
# Extract name from the string 
df['SIN1'] = df['INVOICE_NUMBER'].str.extract(r'(SINNL.\d+.\d+)', expand=True) 
df['SIN2'] = df['INVOICE_NUMBER'].str.extract(r'(SINNL.\d+.\d+)$', expand=True) # notice the $ here
df
```

[image]